# rHow do you modify this function to return an image path?

Tags: android, android-gallery

So I found a function that would prompt the use to open the gallery of the device. But upon searching around I couldn't find anything that would help me modify this to return an image path. They say something about onActivityResult() which I put on the void itself and is then rejected. Any help on this?

```
public void chooser() {
      AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
         = new AlertDialog.Builder(IPAddress.this);

         myDialog.setTitle("Import Menu Images");

         LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(IPAddress.this);
         layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         myDialog.setView(layout);

         myDialog.setPositiveButton("Open Folder", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             // do something when the button is clicked
             public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
              }
             });

         myDialog.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             // do something when the button is clicked
             public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                 arg0.dismiss();
              }
             });

         myDialog.show();
}
```

I would like it to return the path of the image selected and then I would use that path to copy the said file and save it to a directory I have created on OnCreate of the activity.

Also, I can't seem to be able to debug the said function as when I click the "Open Folder" button, it would give an error saying

`The application Camera(process.com.android.gallery) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

which I've tried multiple times. I even added a front camera to the emulator.

The function is called here :

```
    Button menu_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
    menu_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        chooser();
        }

    });
```

So I would like the chooser to return a string(?) type if it is possible which I would then use to File Copy and then rename.

Comment: How is this method called? Where do you want to return the path to?

Comment: I'll post where it is called sory please wait a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default app chooser can be queried by following way.

```
Button galleryBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery_btn);
        galleryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 2);

            }
        });
```

And you'll receive the selected file's URi in onActivityResult() of your activity/fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Uri uriString = null;

        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {

                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri,
                                new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA },
                                null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();


                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(0));
                File file = new File(cursor.getString(0));

                uriString = Uri.fromFile(file);

         // do processing with the uri here

                cursor.close();

            }

        }else{
            Log.e("RDT", "Something went wrong.");
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: its Bitmap object .. refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html